Is there a way to send HTTPS requests to a public IP address via node package HTTPS?
I'm trying to send HTTPS requests to a public IP address or URL. I'm using the HTTPS module of node.js, and I'm using the .request() method to attempt to send requests, however, I do not know how to proceed from here. I've tried to find documentation but those didn't work as well.
I found documentation online, and when I inputted a URL, it just logged nothing. Again, the code I was trying to use was:
const request = https.request(url, (res) => {
 // don't know what to do from here
});


By the way, you tagged python-requests but your question is about nodejs. in python, just in case that is actually what you need, very simple: """import requests;print(requests.get('https://example.com'))"""

This question is similar to: Steps to send a https request to a rest service in Node js. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Eventhough it's possible with the https package, I'd suggest to use the native fetch instead. Because (1) it's easier to use, and (2) it's compatible with the browser's fetch interface, ie just one thing to learn and remember for all JS environments

"I've tried to find documentation but those didn't work as well." What docs did you consult? What didn't work with those docs? The offical docs of the Node https package provide a complete example on how to do a request.

Right from the docs.
const https = require('node:https');

https.get('https://example.com/', (res) => {
  console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
  console.log('headers:', res.headers);

  res.on('data', (d) => {
    process.stdout.write(d);
  });

}).on('error', (e) => {
  console.error(e);
});

You need to do something with the data. Here's a more complete example that prompts for a url.
const https = require('https');
const readline = require('readline');

// initialize readline
const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

// Prompt for uri
rl.question('>>: ', (url) => {
  // Make the request
  const request = https.request(url, (res) => {
    let data = '';

    /* Reading data in chunks is best practice
    */
    res.on('data', (chunk) => {
      data += chunk;
    });

    // Print response 
    res.on('end', () => {
      console.log('Response:', data);
      rl.close(); // Close the readline interface
    });
  });

  // Handle request errors
  request.on('error', (error) => {
    console.error('Request Error:', error);
    rl.close(); // Close the readline interface on error
  });

  // End the request to send 
  request.end();
});


You need to do something with the res object, since that contains the response of the request. For example, you could write the content of the page to the console:
  res.on('data', (d) => {
    console.log(d);
  });

Or print the status code to see if the request was succesful (200):
  console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);

I found the above in the documentation for the HTTPS module of NodeJS on their site here: https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#httpsrequesturl-options-callback
They also have examples!


I'm trying to send HTTPS requests to a public IP address or URL. I'm using the HTTPS module of node.js, and I'm using the .request() method to attempt to send requests

If the use of https module isn't a constraint, in many kind of JavaScript framework (mainly React.js and React Native), and pure JavaScript, axios is more often used.
Because it's more convenient and easy to use, it also allows to catch all request (before it sends) and response (before you receive) if you want to edit something.
Simple example from the documentation:
import axios from 'axios';

// HTTP GET method
axios.get('/user?ID=12345')
  .then(function (response) {
    // handle success
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    // handle error
    console.log(error);
  })
  .finally(function () {
    // always executed
  });

// HTTP POST method
axios.post('/user', {
    email: "name@domain"
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  })
  .finally(function () {
    // always executed
  });

// Want to use async/await? Add the `async` keyword to your outer function/method.
async function getUser() {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post('/user'{
    email: "name@domain"
  });
    console.log(response);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

